# indexing a table which keeps inserting data per day

Tags: sql, mysql, django, django-models

I am using django for the backend and i used
`db_index = True` 
for one field, the table keeps inserting data every 3 minutes(because a machine sends data with this period and django receives and stores it in related table) and now I am wondering if there is problem with this approach. i mean for indexing.
Thanks

Comment: Generally indices require maintenance -exact work depends on the backend database, and the options Django chooses to create them. First and foremost the presence will slow down the inserts a little, but how many rows do you add every three minutes? and how are the new values coming in distributed so how it impacts the index structure... if you need the index for searching/sorting/joining frequently, I would leave it intact and observe

Comment: thanks  for your response, i have about 80 tables that they get  one row of data every 3 minutes , the index is on the datetime field which the data is inserted. and exactly i need the index for the same reasons you mentioned @tinazmu

Comment: I would keep the index if it is useful for other queries.